# Is NAT the same as a Routing with DHCP in the virtual VMnet 8 (NAT) in VMWare?

Tags: routing, dhcp, virtual-machines, nat

Is NAT the same as a Routing with DHCP in the virtual VMnet 8 (NAT) in VMWare? Or how does the routing take place in these virtual environments?

Answer (score 0):

No.

How a host gets an IP address is unrelated to how traffic from it is subsequently NATed and routed or just routed. That is decided by the configuration of the gateway/router it uses to communicate with another host/network.

Answer (score 0):

Basically No.

This is a potentially dangerous misunderstanding, not sure how you came to have it. Perhaps you should try asking a broader question about what your trying to achieve.

Also read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) on NAT.

Comment: Ok I was into the VMWare Elearning and the VMNet 8. It says it is NAT, but it doesnt say something about that is i  a router as well, which it must be, since its getting addresses in a subrange and gets out on the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

No

First you should differentiate Routing and Forwarding.

Routing determines the packages complete way through the network.

The process of Forwarding instead decribes the decisions taken by a single node to communicate to the next neighbor.

NAT (Network Address Translation) describes methods to used to replace the adressinformation transmitted in a packet.

Comment: And DHCP is a method of providing address, default gateway, DNS and other information.